# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 8192 Message: Non-static method User::getAllforDisplayActive() should not be called statically

Tags: php, continuous-integration

```
public function view_with_paging(){

    $halamanke = $this->input->post('halaman');
    $offset = ($halamanke-1)*BARIS_PER_HALAMAN;

    $vars['users'] = user::getAllforDisplayActive($offset);      

    $vars['halamanke'] = $halamanke;        
    $this->load->view('user_management/view_user_paging_view', $vars);
}
```

Comment: create a new user

by caling $user = new User()  and then call
$user->getAllforDisplayActive($offset);
Or in your User class make the method getAllforDisplayActive($offset) static.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message itself.
`getAllforDisplayActive()` is not a static method so you should instantiate a new `user` object and call the method like this

```
$user = new User();
$user->getAllforDisplayActive($offset);
```

Or, as already noted in the comments, you can make the method static in the class definition of the `user` class